# How do I parallelize I/O-bound operations in Python?

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm processing tweets with tweepy:

```
class StdOutListener(StreamListener):
    def on_data(self, data):
        process(json.loads(data))
        return True

l = StdOutListener()
stream = Stream(auth, l)
stream.filter(track=utf_words)
```

The `process` function gets contents of URLs (with requests) included into tweets, processes the data with nltk (I guess this uses a bit of CPU) and saves the result into Mongo.

The problem is that getting contents of included URLs takes long time and hence limits my processing speed. How do I pythonically speed this thing up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use python's `threading` module:

```
import threading

class YourThreadSubclass(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self,your_args):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        #do whatever setup you want
    
    def run(self):
        process_data(self.some_property)

threads = [YourThreadSubclass(args) for args in Iterable]
for t in threads:
    t.start()
for t in threads:
    t.join()
return reduce(combiner, (t.result_field for t in threads))
```

More info here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html

edit: More directly, you could fork off a thread whenever on_data is called.

```
def on_data(self, data):
    YourThreadSubclass(data).start()
```

The forked thread would store its results asynchronously.

If you're dealing with a lot of requests, you might also want to use a thread pool to manage your threads. Docs [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers)

Comment: I don't have any Iterable here, StreamListener treats incoming tweets as events, calls on_data function and blocks until it's done. I'm not sure about how should I adapt your example to my case.

Comment: Edited for clarification.